# how to group events using only a 'release' variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

The only independent variable would be the "release" period.

Do you know what this sort of query would be called?

Is this sort of query is already available as a built-in function or otherwise?

If not, what is the best approach for a problem like this?

I'd like for the "window" table to be a "view" since the events available are constantly changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this exemplary table of events:

```
create table events(id serial primary key, start_time timestamp);
insert into events (start_time) values
    ('2017-11-10 12:00'),
    ('2017-11-10 12:32'),
    ('2017-11-10 12:39'),
    ('2017-11-10 12:42'),
    ('2017-11-10 13:55'),
    ('2017-11-10 14:19');
```

use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to calculate the distance in time between events.

For example, if `release` is half an hour:

```
select distinct
    first_value(id) over w_asc as window_start,
    first_value(id) over w_desc as window_end
from (
    select 
        id, start_time, 
        sum(series) over (order by start_time) as series
    from (
        select
            id, start_time, 
            (start_time - lag(start_time) over w >= '0:30')::int series
        from events
        window w as (order by start_time)
        ) e
    ) e
where series is not null
window 
    w_asc as (partition by series order by start_time),
    w_desc as (partition by series order by start_time desc)

 window_start | window_end 
--------------+------------
            2 |          4
            5 |          6
(2 rows)
```

Read in the documentation [about window functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: Given your sample data there should be two windows: 2-4 and 5-6

Comment: I think your answer over yonder is kind of what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404819/2253532

Comment: I must have read the question carelessly, sorry. See the updated answer.

Comment: you are a beast